# No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu

I recently upgraded (with `apt-get dist-upgrade`) my Kubuntu and Lubuntu Linux boxes, and now **every time** I log into one of these machines, I get this message:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

Here is a screenshot of the exact message:
[image: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified]

This happened on both my Lubuntu machine and Kubuntu machine, and it wasn't a problem until after I upgraded; so I suspect that it was not user error.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

I have tracked this down to my .bashrc file, which is getting called by my .profile file.  Though, the fact that my .bashrc file now runs when I do a GUI login whereas it didn't before I upgraded is a bit weird.  And no, I haven't modified my .bashrc file or my .profile recently.  Also, bash isn't my default shell.

The problem is that I am calling `tput` in my .bashrc file to set up variables for use in adding color to the prompt.  But at the (inappropriate) time when my .bashrc file now gets run, `$TERM` is not set.

```
fgRed=$(tput setaf 1)     ; fgGreen=$(tput setaf 2)  ; fgBlue=$(tput setaf 4)
fgMagenta=$(tput setaf 5) ; fgYellow=$(tput setaf 3) ; fgCyan=$(tput setaf 6)
fgWhite=$(tput setaf 7)   ; fgBlack=$(tput setaf 0)
bgRed=$(tput setab 1)     ; bgGreen=$(tput setab 2)  ; bgBlue=$(tput setab 4)
bgMagenta=$(tput setab 5) ; bgYellow=$(tput setab 3) ; bgCyan=$(tput setab 6)
bgWhite=$(tput setab 7)   ; bgBlack=$(tput setab 0)
```

**Updated question:** How should I fix this?  Should I set `$TERM` myself?  Or should I just not set these variables if `$TERM` is not set?

**UPDATE 2**

One solution I tried was to check whether `$TERM` was set. But this didn't seem to work; I still got the same error message.  Here's the code:

```
if [ ! "$TERM" = "" ]; then
  #Do stuff here
fi
```

So apparently `$TERM` *was* set, but `tput` still concluded it wasn't.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `.profile` runs regardless of the default shell

Comment: @Serg but during a GUI shell login?  Also, I didn't always see this problem.

Comment: Well, yeah, it should be ran upon user loging in and this is exactly what you were doing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What ultimately worked for me was to check whether the shell was an interactive shell.  I based the solution on this other post at unix.stackexchange: [How to check if a shell is login/interactive/batch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26676/83381).

So the code for the solution was:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
  fgRed=$(tput setaf 1)     ; fgGreen=$(tput setaf 2)  ; fgBlue=$(tput setaf 4)
  fgMagenta=$(tput setaf 5) ; fgYellow=$(tput setaf 3) ; fgCyan=$(tput setaf 6)
  fgWhite=$(tput setaf 7)   ; fgBlack=$(tput setaf 0)
  bgRed=$(tput setab 1)     ; bgGreen=$(tput setab 2)  ; bgBlue=$(tput setab 4)
  bgMagenta=$(tput setab 5) ; bgYellow=$(tput setab 3) ; bgCyan=$(tput setab 6)
  bgWhite=$(tput setab 7)   ; bgBlack=$(tput setab 0)
fi
```

Comment: Aha, that's an elegant solution. :)

Comment: If this is in `.bashrc`, I find it surprising. The default `.bashrc` contains: `# If not running interactively, don't do anything`
`case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;`, so your settings shouldn't be applied unless interactive.

Comment: @muru My .bashrc file is very non-default. :)

Comment: But where did you do that? in `.bashrc`?

Comment: I think if you put this at the top of your file it's cleaner: `[[ $- == *i* ]] || return` Ref: (https://askubuntu.com/a/1070182/362122)

Answer (score 10):

If you do this

```
if tty -s
then
    : # your tput commands
fi
```

It will fix your problem.
Without the -s option tty will either display your tty or write "not a tty"

Comment: The description of `tty` from its [manual page](https://man.cx/tty) is "print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input." If the stdin of your script is a pipe, this test will fail, with the consequence being your program stops printing colors in its _output_ just because its _input_ is coming from a pipe. Maybe `test -t 1` (in English: "is stdout connected to a terminal?") is what you really want? That way you get colors _only_ if the output is going to a terminal, and you won't see weird terminal codes if you redirect its output to a file or pipe it through, say, `less`.

Answer (score 8):

For me, adding

```
export TERM=xterm
```

to `/etc/profile` was the only thing that solved the problem. Actually, the error gave us a hint: `No value for $TERM`

Answer (score 5):

[*Different scenario, but search engine lead me here first]*

When "*tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified*" error occurs in a **Docker** container (for me, when opening a **zsh** shell calling `docker exec -it <container> zsh` (-i for interactive)) the only way to fix this, was to set the variable like `ENV TERM xterm-256color` in the Dockerfile for this image.

Approaches like `RUN export TERM=xterm-256color`  or `RUN echo "export TERM=xterm-256color" >> ~/.zshrc` were not successful. Other values for TERM are also possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening terminal (doesn't matter which, even tty1 will do) and run this line

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`

You will be presented with choice of the default terminal emulator for x window. Choose one by selecting number, and reboot after you're done.

$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 6 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

```
  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/sakura                   40        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: When I try this, it tells me "There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator [...] Nothing to configure".  This is on my Kubuntu machine.

Comment: Try installing another terminal emulator, for instance `gnome-terminal` or `sakura`

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I have selected `sakura`. However, this seems to be a problem with the gnome terminal wrapper; if so, why not fix that?

Comment: It does not fix the problem, actually.

Comment: @jjmerelo As OP later revealed in his answer, he had lines in his .bashrc file, which was giving the error. Gnome terminal wrapper shouldn't be the issue. My guess initially was that $TERM variable wasn't set, which is was another user, Gunnar, mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error dialog is due to the fix of [bug #678421](https://launchpad.net/bugs/678421), so it's my fault. ;) It tells you about errors due to some command(s) in one of your configuration files. If you scroll to the top, you can see which file is causing the error messages.

Possibly Serg's answer is sufficient to get rid of the warning dialog.

*Edit:*

Would like to add a couple of things due to the updated question.

Unlike before, `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session` is now run under bash (previously sh). That's why its sourcing of `~/.profile` results in `~/.profile` sourcing `~/.bashrc`. Possibly this means that the default contents of `~/.profile` ought to be changed.

The easiest thing you can do to fix it is, as you suggested, to only call tput if $TERM is set.

Comment: I tried checking whether $TERM was set, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Sildoreth: Can you please show us the exact code for doing so? (Please edit your question again.)

Comment: added to question

Comment: @Sildoreth: Saw it. Maybe it's because tput is called in subprocesses. (Just a guess.) Anyway, you found a nice way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

---

### --> MY WORKING SOLUTION FOR THE TPUT-PROBLEM:

---

```
# when $TERM is empty (non-interactive shell), then expand tput with '-T xterm-256color'
[[ ${TERM}=="" ]] && TPUTTERM='-T xterm-256color' \
                  || TPUTTERM=''

declare -r    RES='tput${TPUTTERM} sgr0'       REV='tput${TPUTTERM} rev'
declare -r    fRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 1'    bRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 1'
declare -r    fGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 2'    bGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 2'
...
echo ${fRD}" RED Message: ${REV} This message is RED REVERSE. "${RES}
echo ${fGN}" GREEN Message: ${REV} This message is GREEN REVERSE. "${RES}
...
```

That way the tput command is still working as fine as possible and 
it makes no sense if it is an interactive or non-interactive shell...

*6a5h4*