# How return from .bashrc if not run interactively?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I have two statements to return from `~/.bashrc` if the shell is not interactive, probably from two Ubuntu versions, but I can't reconstruct which one is newer (and I assume thus better) and I'm interested in the effect of the different approaches:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

vs.

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: You can write it more tersely: `[[ $- == *i* ]] || return`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour#interactive_shell), the most reliable method is to check for the existance of the `i` letter in the variable `$-` (your second method).

There are cleaner ways to implement this action, like the following:

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return
```

For more information, check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26782/107625) on the Unix&Linux StackExchange community.