# Error found when loading /home/[username]/.profile, tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: 20.04, session, .profile, configure, xterm

When I login to my system, I got this popup:

```
Error found when loading /home/[username]/.profile:

tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

Someone, please give a suggestion, how to get rid of this. I am a complete beginner in Linux.

Comment: `mv $HOME/.profile $HOME/.profile.bak` then cp the default from `cp /etc/profile $HOME/.profile` to your home.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No value for $TERM and no -T specified](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591937/no-value-for-term-and-no-t-specified)